# Is it a bad practice to leave unimportant Promises unresolved?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, promise

I'm trying to wrap my head around a practice that I've now noticed across different codebases where functions are leaving supplementary async function calls unresolved.

I assume that this is done to potentially save on performance, as waiting for the promise to be resolved might add additional overhead to gain no real benefit (if the promise is not important to the result of the function) other than guarantee that everything has finished.

A common example I've seen of this is with caching:

```
async function someFunction() {

  const result = await doSomething();
  
  cacheResult(result);
  
  return result;
}

async function cacheResult(someValue) {
  // ... cache logic returning a promise
}
```

Am I correct to assume that in the above example, there exists a scenario where `someFunction` has finished before `cacheResult` is resolved? If so then I assume that `cacheResult` will resolve "at some arbitrary time later"?

What if I have `someFunction` wrapped in a `try/catch` block:

```
try {
  await someFunction();
} catch (error) {
  // ... error handling
}
```

But `cacheResult` promise resolves into a rejection some time later. Will this result in an unhandled promise rejection and terminate the process even though I had it surrounded in `try/catch`?

Assuming that proper error handling is in place for `cacheResult` and it is a complex function taking a considerable amount of time, is it a valid practice to then leave it to resolve on its own and continue with processing to not lose performance?

Comment: Are you asking about never resolving promises (so that they stay pending), or asking about never `await`ing promises (so that you ignore their results)

Comment: "*Will this result in an unhandled promise rejection and terminate the process?*" - yes. So don't do that. Always add error handling when you end a promise chain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am I correct to assume that in the above example, there exists a scenario where someFunction has finished before cacheResult is resolved?

In fact, it's pretty much guaranteed. `cacheResult` will immediately execute but it won't resolve yet (unless you don't do *any* async work and immediately return). To illustrate:

```
async function doSomething() {
  return 1;
}

async function someFunction() {

  const result = await doSomething();

  cacheResult(result).then(console.log);

  return result;
}

async function cacheResult(someValue) {
  await null; // have this function take at least one tick.
  return 2;
}

someFunction().then(console.log);
// Logs 1, then 2.
```

> If so then I assume that cacheResult will resolve "at some arbitrary time later"?

Yes.

In fact, if `cacheResult` was implemented like this, it would not even resolve at all:

```
function cacheResult(someValue) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // don't do anything with resolve() or reject()
  });
}
```

> But cacheResult promise resolves into a rejection some time later. Will this result in an unhandled promise rejection and terminate the process even though I had it surrounded in try/catch?

Yes. This will not catch exceptions in the `cacheResult` call and will result in an unhandled promise rejection:

```
// Make it throw an error:
async function cacheResult(someValue) {
  await null; // have this function take at least one tick.
  throw new Error('Custom error');
}
// Run Node with warnings enabled:
// node --unhandled-rejections=warn example.js
// UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. 
// This error originated either by throwing inside of an async 
// function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which 
// was not handled with .catch(). (...)
```

The error message points you at this answer, in fact.

> Assuming that proper error handling is in place for cacheResult and it is a complex function taking a considerable amount of time, is it a valid practice to then leave it to resolve on its own and continue with processing to not lose performance?

Yes, that's totally fine:

```
async function someFunction() {

  const result = await doSomething();

  cacheResult(result).catch(err => console.warn("cacheResult:", err));

  return result;
}
```

*You might want to consider adding a mechanism that makes sure that a slow `cacheResult()` call doesn't overwrite a newer `cacheResult()` that just happened to finish sooner (eg save a timestamp or a revision number).*

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's bad practice to have ever-pending promises, because they occupy resources.

But there are no (obvious) unresolved promises in your example. Just because you don't `await` a promise, this doesn't mean it won't resolve (assuming that `cacheResult` eventually finishes). And yes, it's totally fine, to don't await promises if you don't care for their result right now.

But yes, your code will throw an unhandled promise rejection, even if you wrap your `await someFunction()` into a `try {...} catch {...}` block, because you lose the context for the promise returned by `cacheResult`. Ie the async code in `someFunction()` will long be finished (and the promise returned by it will long be resolved (or maybe rejected)) before the promise returned by `cacheResult` will either resolve or reject.

So, if you don't want to await `cacheResult` or you don't care whether it's successful or not, either make it to not throw under any circumstances by doing

```
async function cacheResult(foo) {
  try {
    //some async code
  } catch {
    //optional error handling/logging
  }
}
```

or add a rejectionhandler, when you call it

```
async function someFunction() {
   //some code
   cacheResult(...).catch(e => {
     //optional error handling/logging
   })
   //some more code
}
```

Both of these variants will let `cacheResult` finishing somewhat later but still catch any error it throws.

But be aware of one thing: For instance nodejs may not wait for pending promises and terminate nonetheless, so your `cacheResult` function may be terminated at any time, if there is nothing else going on keeping your process alive ...

Comment: "*because they occupy resources*" - actually they don't, if their resolver functions are garbage-collected and they are not referenced themselves